# The subcategory ModR is finitely generated R-modules has always cokernels but has kernels only if R is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have to prove that the subcategory modR of finitely generated R-modules has always cokernels but has kernels only when R is a Noetherian ring.

I know how to prove that ModR has cokernels is it the same?
And about the second part I can I do this proving that modR is abelian iff R is Noetherian?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, quotients of finitely generated modules are always finitely generated (no hypothesis needed on the ring), but submodules are not always finitely generated unless the ring is noetherian (this is exactly what noetherian means). So this is why you always get cokernels (quotients), but you need that $R$ is noetherian to get kernels (submodules).

Comment: And is this enough as a proof?

Comment: Well you need to justify why in this category having cokernels (resp. kernels) amounts to having quotients (resp. submodules). But this is the core of the argument.

Comment: Ok I understand thank you very much